# java reset game method, number of games played not incrementing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, reset

I'm trying to put together a game, However, i'm not sure how to tackle the reset function.  I have made it so that the game resets, this works, however, on game restart, the label that is supposed to display how many games the player has played does not change from 0.  Heres what I have done so far.

The display and positioning of labels...

```
private int noGamesPlayed;
private JLabel gamesPlayed = new JLabel("Games Played = " + noGamesPlayed);
getContentPane().add(gamesPlayed);
gamesPlayed.setBounds(60,60+gridsize*boardsize,130,30);
```

The reset function...

```
public void reset(){

 game.this.setVisible(false);
 game.this.dispose();
 new game();
 updateGamesPlayed();   
}
```

The function that is suppose to update the games played...

```
 public void updateGamesPlayed() {
 noGamesPlayed ++;
 gamesPlayed.setText("" + noGamesPlayed + " Games Played");

}
```

Help Appreciated.

Comment: I supposed the updateGamesPlayed() is in the game class?

Comment: If it is, (and noGamesPlayed is not static) you are re-initializing the variable when you call 'new game()'

Comment: It is in the game class yes, is there a way of increment the variable when the game is reset?

Comment: Make it a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the noOfGamesPlayed variable to static. That field does not belong to the object, but to the class itself. Then, change the updateGamesPlayed to a static method, this way all game objects will see the same numberOfGamesPlayed count. Like that:

```
private static int noGamesPlayed = 0;

public static void updateGamesPlayed() {
    noGamesPlayed ++;
}
```

Then, on the reset method, create a new game **after** updating the number of games played.

```
public void reset(){
    game.this.setVisible(false);
    game.this.dispose();
    updateGamesPlayed();   
    new game();
}
```

You can also make it "automatic" by incrementing the `noGamesPlayed` on the game constructor. That way you don't need to call `updateGamesPlayed`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a completely new game object, one that has its own noGamesPlayed variable and JTextField, and likely this method call is not changing the gamesPlayed JTextField in the newly displayed GUI

```
gamesPlayed.setText("" + noGamesPlayed + " Games Played");
```

but rather is updating the JTextField of the GUI that has been disposed of. Note that your reset method looks to be recursive.

One solution is to call the `updateGamesPlayed(...)` method of the newly created game object (note that the class should be renamed Game), and pass in the correct number as a parameter.

Myself, I'd go about resetting my game in a completely different way, by not creating a new window, but instead by updating the key model variables (the non-GUI variables and classes that determine the state of your program) and then using those variables to reset the current display.

Comment: I think your way is much, better and I'll look into doing it your way when I make some improvements, for now its working with the reset. Thanks.